# window.addEventListener on a message emitted from an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, addeventlistener, postmessage

I have two html files. The first is called `post.html` and it registers an event listener on the window and posts a message to the window:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                console.log("found event in post!", event)
            }); 
            window.postMessage({
               'data': ["some data"]
            },"*");   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a second html file called `listner.html` that just listens for a message from the window and loads `post.html` as an iframe:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
              console.log("event found in listen!", event)
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="post.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I load `listener.html`, I get the log indicating that the event listener in `post.html` detected the message posted to the window in `post.html` but I don't get any log from `listener.html`. My understanding was that I should be able to communicate via the `window` object between the two files and the event listener in `listener.html` should receive the event. Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post.html` is posting the message to its own window, and not to the window containing `listener.html`

```
window.parent.postMessage(...)
```