# How can get click listener from my Iframe?

Tags: html, angular, angular8, angular9

My apps is an Iframe  id= "if1"  and there is:

App A1 contains my apps "if1"

How can i check if i click out my iframe "if1" ?

I try to use this solution but it doesn't work for me :

https://gist.github.com/micdenny/db03a814eaf4cd8abf95f77885d9316f

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Also this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54519710/window-addeventlistener-on-a-message-emitted-from-an-iframe